# How "chilled" can be used as verb?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, adjectives

I am confused about word **chilled**. I understand the use of **chilled** as an Adjective.For example

> The soup is chilled

Here chilled is a adjective which refer to cool

But How can i use "chilled". as a verb and how I can decide whether it is verb or adjective

For example I just watched a video on http://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/everyday-grammar-subjunctive/3458590.html. In that video, man speaks this sentence at  1:16

> I suggest that you wait until the Soup has chilled.

Is the "soup has chilled" is a present perfect tense where chilled is third form of **chill** Or is it a present simple tense, Where chilled is used as adjective .

Comment: *to chill* usually means "to make *something else* cold", so with food, we normally use it in the passive voice, like "The soup *has been chilled*.  It *was chilled* by putting it in the refrigerator for a while."

Comment: Context is vital to any understanding; it is entirely possible that *chilled* is a verb in the passive form in *The soup is chilled*. *Soup has chilled* is unnatural either way.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, which makes the point about the importance of context to understanding. *I suggest that you wait until the soup has chilled* is perfectly fine, whereas *soup has chilled* on its own is rather peculiar.

Comment: @choster, if the soup was really agitated and upset, and then it calmed itself down, you could say "the soup has chilled".  But I suppose it is unnatural for soup to have emotions (although how can we really know?), so I guess even though it would be grammatically correct, you could still say it's unnatural.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

"Chill!" This means (in NAm Eng) that I am asking you to calm down, relax.

"I need to chill this soup before I serve it."

> chill  (from Google Dictionary)
>
> > noun
> >
> > - 1. an unpleasant feeling of coldness in the atmosphere, one's surroundings, or the body. "there was a chill in the air"
> >
> > synonyms:   coldness, chilliness, coolness, iciness, rawness, bitterness, nip "a chill in the air"
> >
> > - 2. a metal mold or part of a mold, often cooled, designed to ensure rapid or even cooling of metal during casting.
> >
> > verb
> >
> > - 1. make (someone) cold. "I'm chilled to the bone"
> > - 2. horrify or frighten (someone). "the city was chilled by the violence"
> >
> > synonyms:    scare, frighten, petrify, terrify, alarm
> >
> > adjective
> >
> > - 1. chilly. "the chill gray dawn" synonyms: cold, chilly, cool, fresh
> > - 2. NORTH AMERICAN informal very relaxed or easy going. "I'm kind of a relaxed, chill guy"